# SMPTE TimeCode from Quick Time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

How do I get the timecode start and the duration of a QT movie? I've figured out that I have to use QTKIt and maybe QTStringFromSMPTETime but I couldn't find any example on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using QTKit and the QuickTime API:

```
QTTrack * tcTrack = [[self.movie tracksOfMediaType:QTMediaTypeTimeCode] objectAtIndex:0];
if (tcTrack != nil) {
    QTMedia * media = [tcTrack media];
    if (media != nil) {
        NSLog(@"sample : %@", [media attributeForKey:QTMediaSampleCountAttribute]);
        Media qtMedia = [media quickTimeMedia];
        MediaHandler mh = GetMediaHandler(qtMedia);
        long frameNum;
        TimeCodeDef tcDef;
        TimeCodeRecord tcData;
        UserData srcRefH;
        TCGetTimeCodeAtTime(mh, 0, &frameNum, &tcDef, &tcData, &srcRefH);
        // frameNum holds the frame number since 00:00:00:00
        // tcData holds the HH:MM:SS:FF data
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason that Media, MediaHandler, TimeCodeDef, and TimeCodeRecord are all producing undeclared identifier errors?  Even with the correct frameworks included.  Have these gone legacy?

Comment: Okay, just wanted to share this with folks.  Apparently the Quicktime API will not run in 64-bit mode, so this example code HAS to be run in 32-bit.  Hope Apple updates THAT soon.

Comment: If anyone has had ANY luck getting this to work in a 64bit environment, I'd really appreciate hearing about it.

Comment: I did it but using the AVFoundation framework. Tell me if you're interested!

Comment: I don't think Apple is going to update a 20 year old API! QuickTime got introduced in the beginning 90s and will never be 64 bit. That's why Apple introduces AVFoundation. For now, you have to either use the QTKit stuff ( which can't do any advanced work ) or stick with the old API and use 32 bit. I honestly don't see the big point in not using 32 bit for now ....

Comment: @tinmaru I am incredibly interested, yes.  Could you send me over an example of how you did it?

Comment: The AVFoundation version is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083325/how-to-get-the-start-timecode-smpte-of-a-quicktime-movie-in-objective-c-in-64/12103238#12103238