# Offset timecode via avfoundation

Tags: ios, cocoa, avfoundation

Is there any way to somehow access or construct the "offset timecode" (or start timecode) of a QuickTime movie using AVFoundation?

The only way I manage to get hold of this information is using QTKit and QuickTime via TCGetCurrentTimeCode() on QTMedia of the timecode QTTrack. Quicktime however is not 64 bit and I would rather use AVFoundation if possible.

[aAVAsset tracks] lets me get a handle on the AVAssetTrack representing the timecode track which holds this information. I explored the available information via formatdescription but there was nothing that seemed to be of help and I could also not find any way to access the raw data of the timecode track.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be a dupe of an issue I was having just recently.  I hope this solves your issue!

[How to get the Start Timecode (SMPTE) of a Quicktime-Movie in Objective-C in 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083325/how-to-get-the-start-timecode-smpte-of-a-quicktime-movie-in-objective-c-in-64)

Comment: The only thing missing here is getting the flag as the whether or not this is Drop or Non-Drop, which is necessarily in building the start timecode from the frame count.  If anyone has that, then this would be complete!

Comment: AVAssetReader... I see. Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.